# Get custom field value in web-item(velocity) context

Tags: jira, velocity, jira-plugin

Basically I'm trying to predefine some values with URL by creating a web-item with link to CreateIssueDetails!init.jspa operation:

```
<web-item key="has-defect" name="has-defect" section="operations-operations">
        <label>Has Defect</label>
        <link linkId="issueaction-has-defect">/secure/CreateIssueDetails!init.jspa?ppid=$issue.id&amp;pid=$issue.project.id&amp;issuetype=27&amp;lname=Defect&amp;customfield_10056=$issue.getCustomField("customfield_10056").name&amp;assignee=$issue.assignee.name&amp;customfield_10011=$issue.getCustomFieldValue("customfield_10011")&amp;customfield_10046=10248&amp;customfield_10022=$issue.getCustomFieldValue("customfield_10022")</link>
</web-item>
```

Assume I have an Issue with custom field "Some Custom Fied" value in it, is it possible get it's value from issue like I'm getting for example Assignee: `$issue.assignee`.

I've already tried :

```
$issue.getCustomField("customfield_10056").value;
$issue.getCustomField("customfield_10056").name;
$issue.getCustomFieldValue("customfield_10056")
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

A web-item is defined in an atlassian-plugin.xml file, but you're expecting it to behave like a Velocity template file. I don't think that $issue will be expanded as you want, or is it?

Comment: Well I successfully can extract in atlassian-plugin.xml file simple fields from Issue like Assigne($issue.assignee), project($issue.project) and so on. Take a look at code in the question - everything except getting info from customfields works.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do this in 2 steps:

```
#set($customFieldObj = $customFieldManager.getCustomFieldObject("customfield_10056"))
```

"customfield_10056" is the field identifier.

And then:

```
$cutomFieldObj.getValue($issue))
```

It must work.

Answer (score 0):

You should extend `AbstractJiraContextProvider`.

Example here:

https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/tutorial-jira-add-content-to-view-issue-screen/src/58aca50e970125b34fb70bde1edac9a29cb67a9e/src/main/java/com/example/plugins/tutorial/DueDateIndicator.java

And inside you web-item you can use the context-provider:

```
  <context-provider class="com.example.plugins.tutorial.DueDateIndicator"/>
```